# "Could not find column with id..." when trying to create an angular mat-table from a JSON

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding, angular-material, mat-table

I have a hard time creating a dynamically generated angular mat-table from a JSON. It's going to be a bit complicated to explain as I need to have 4 components working together to get that table. 
The table will look something like this [Table general structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEetp.png)

It comes from a Json with that structure (only one element of colum and row to avoid taking too much space)

```
{"sessionID": "jdshfjksg12432dksfjl",
    "mainObjectGUID": "lmmljlmfdkjgkj- hsqjkhgdkqj - sqsfdzeg",
    "userGUID": "ushdshfjdfskjdshfjkdshkj",
    "column": [{
      "name": "ObjectGUID",
      "accessJSON": "objectGUID",
      "type": "String",
      "visible": false,
      "columnSize": null,
      "dropdownList": null,
      "controlType": null,
      "control": null
    },]
     "rows": [{
      "ObjectGUID": "djsklgfsdhjlk- fdhjhg - dkfsjgfl",
      "columnName": "idCompany",
      "Type": "Integer",
      "primaryKey": true,
      "Mandatory": true,
      "updated": false
    },]
}
```

My issue is, I can't hardcode containers for each and every column of the table as they contain different types of data (text, select field or checkbox), and everything must be created dinamically as the Json will change.
So I created 3 sub-components for the three situations (text, select field and checkbox field). 
For now I'd only try to make the text data work.

Here is my main component

```
    import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
    // @ts-ignore
    import mockData from '../../../assets/mock.json';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-tab',
      templateUrl: './tab.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./tab.component.scss']
    })
    export class TabComponent implements OnInit {

      constructor() { }
      displayedColumns: string[] =[];
      dataSource: Array<any> = mockData.rows;
      columnNames: string[] = [];

      ngOnInit() {
        this.createColumnNamesAndDisplayed();
      }

      click() {
        console.log('data', this.dataSource);
      }

      createColumnNamesAndDisplayed(){
        for (const col of mockData.column){
          if (col.visible === true){
            this.columnNames.push(col.name);
            this.displayedColumns.push(col.accessJSON)
          }
        }

      }

      }
```

```
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8" >

      <app-str-container *ngFor="let x of displayedColumns" colId={{x}} colName="Test data"></app-str-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

    </table>
```

And my component for the text container

```
    import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-str-container',
      templateUrl: './str-container.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./str-container.component.scss']
    })
    export class StrContainerComponent implements OnInit {

      @Input() colName :string;
      @Input()   colId: string;


      constructor() { }


      ngOnInit() {
      }

    }
```

```
    <ng-container matColumnDef={{colId}}>
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{colName}} </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.colId}} </td>
    </ng-container>
```

It's strange to me that I keep getting the issue "Could not find column with id "columnName" coming from tab.component.html as I've had the issue before, understood and adressed it. 
I'm quite new to angular, I'm not very confortable with binding or @input decorator.
If you have another way of achieving what I want, feel free to tell me, I'm probably doing things very wrong.